# How to convert function to lambda

Tags: python, lambda

My function is below

```
def majority(x):
    if x > 17:
        return True
    return False
```

Sample lambda pseudo-code

`majority =  lambda x: if x > 17 return True ? False`

Comment: While it's straightforward to write a lambda expression for this, you almost certainly don't need to.

Comment: FYI in the initial version you did not need to have the extra return False there. if the IF statement is not True it will return False allready.

Comment: @marxmacher that is not entierly true. When a function doesn't have an explicit `return` statement it returns `None`, not `False`

Comment: Right you are. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide an expression. You can do this with python's "conditional expressions"

```
majority = lambda x: True if x > 17 else False
```

however, this just simplifies to

```
majority = lambda x: x > 17
```

---

Conditional expressions are of the form

```py
value_if_true if condition else value_if_false
```